# Break a number into intervals of chunks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a number in excel, Say 15. I want to equal interval chunks split by 3 in three different columns

For example if it is 15, my expected output is

```
A     B    C     D 
15   1-5, 5-10, 10-15
```

Comment: is it always 3 chunks, will the number always divide nicely?  please give more examples or we may solve this specific issue and it may not work for other outliers

Comment: The number of parts depends. For now I want it to be three chunks assuming it divides nicely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so for this specific case:

```
=$A1/3*(COLUMN(A1)-1)+1&"-"&$A1/3*(COLUMN(A1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I would need B to be 1-5, C to be 5-10 & D to be 10-15

Comment: Thats , fine thanks. I am able to get thta by tweaking the formula a bit!.

Comment: if i have mulitple numbers from A2, A3.. will this work if i fill it?